# Why does Cython needs more Python calls if elements of NumPy array are defined during array creation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, cython, cythonize

I don't understand why Cython needs more Python calls to compile my `.pyx` file if I define elements of array during array's creation (`#-1-`).

For the elements `pos1` and `pos2`, `PyFloat_FromDouble` is called four times, twice for each variable, but this function is not used if I create an empty array or array of zeros and change the elements afterwards (`#-2-`).

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sin
from libc.math cimport cos

@cython.boundcheck(False)
@cython.binding(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim = 2] mat (double alfa):
    cdef double pos1 = cos(alfa * 0.01745)
    cdef double pos2 = sin(alfa * 0.01745)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim = 2] mat_ret

    #-1-
    mat_ret = np.array([[pos1, pos2, 0.0],
                        [pos1, pos2, 0.0],
                        [ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0]], dtype = np.float64)

    #-2-
    mat_ret = np.zeros((3,3), dtype = np.float64)
    mat_ret[0,0] = pos1
    mat_ret[0,1] = pos2
    mat_ret[1,0] = pos1
    mat_ret[1,1] = pos2

    return mat_ret
```

I'm using Python 2.7.13, NumPy 1.13.1 and Cython 0.25.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That shouldn't be surprising. Your `pos1` and `pos2` are C doubles, but if you insert them in a list (the `[pos1, pos2, 0.0]` in your code) they need to be Python objects because lists store `PyObject` pointers, thus the call to `PyFloat_FromDouble`. And you really create 3 lists containing 2 `pos1` and 2 `pos2` so you will end up creating 4 lists - the outer one and the inner 3 - and calling `PyFloat_FromDouble` 4 times. And it's going to call `np.array` where these values will be converted to `double`s again!

On the other hand if you create a `np.zeros` array with the "appropriate" dtype it can just insert the `double`s. Because it doesn't have to insert them in an intermediate Python object it doesn't need to box them (`PyFloat_FromDouble`) at all.

Comment: Thank. So, is there a way to create numpy array without this overhead? `numpy.array` function needs lists as its arguments. I should probably create C arrays for arguments, but I'm amazed that Cython won't do that for me. And going this far, by making 2D matrices in C actually makes this solution non pythonic at all

Comment: As far as I know there's no better way (if one wants to avoid lists) than your approach #2 (`np.zeros` and then setting them manually). Maybe it would be easier if one uses memoryviews but not sure about that.